# FFMPEG no audio in final output

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-editing

I have the following FFMPEG command working.

```
ffmpeg -y -i slide.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25:d=1" -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [main]; \
 [1:v] trim=end=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [pre]; \
 [1:v] trim=end=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [post]; \
 [pre][main][post] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [out]" -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

It appends black frames at the start and end of the video. However, the output file does not contain the audio from the input file.

Any pointers to the problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need the original audio with the output file following will work for you. Map the input audio channel to the output using `map` option.

```
-map 0:a -c:a copy
```

You can make it more accurate by appending a silent audio clip to the start and the end of the video to the same duration as the black screen duration. Same way include the following in `filter_complex`.

```
aevalsrc=0:d=1[s];
[s][0:a][s]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa];
```

Here I assumed the duration of the black screen as 1 second. Then map it.

```
-map [outa] -c:a libfdk_aac
```

Hope this will help you!